# Efficiently iterating over 3.311031748 E+12 combinations in Python

Tags: python, loops, bigdata, combinations

I have collected a large Pokemon data set and I am setting out with the goal to identify the 'Top 10 Teams' based on a ratio I constructed - **Pokemon BST (base stat total) : average weakness**. For those who care, I calculate average weakness as the sum of a Pokemon's weakness to each type ( 0.25 to flying + 1 to water + 2 to steel + 4 to fire, etc.) and then divide it by 18 (the total number of types available in game).

To provide a quick example - a team of the following three Pokemon: Kingler, Mimikyu, Magnezone will yield a team ratio of 1604.1365384615383.

Because the data will be used for competitive play, I removed all non-fully evolved Pokemon as well as legendary/mythical Pokemon.  Here is my process so far:

1. Create a collection of all possible combinations of fully evolved Pokemon teams
2. Use a for loop to iterate over each combination
3. The first 10 combinations will automatically be added to the list
4. Starting with the 11th combination, I will add the current team iteration to the list, sort the list in descending order, and then remove the team with the lowest ratio. This ensures only the top 10 will remain after each iteration.

Obviously, this process will take an impossibly long time to run. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to run this. Finally, please see my code below:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Downloads/pokemon.csv")  # read in csv of fully-evolved Pokemon data
# list(df)  # list of df column names - useful to see what data has been collected
df = df[df["is_legendary"] == 0]  # remove legendary pokemon - many legendaries are allowed in competitive play
df = df[['abilities',  # trim df to contain only the columns we care about
        'against_bug',
        'against_dark',
        'against_dragon',
        'against_electric',
        'against_fairy',
        'against_fight',
        'against_fire',
        'against_flying',
        'against_ghost',
        'against_grass',
        'against_ground',
        'against_ice',
        'against_normal',
        'against_poison',
        'against_psychic',
        'against_rock',
        'against_steel',
        'against_water',
        'attack',
        'defense',
        'hp',
        'name',
        'sp_attack',
        'sp_defense',
        'speed',
        'type1',
        'type2']]
df["bst"] = df["hp"] + df["attack"] + df["defense"] + df["sp_attack"] + df["sp_defense"] + df["speed"]  # calculate BSTs
df['average_weakness'] = (df['against_bug'] # calculates a Pokemon's 'average weakness' to other types
                        + df['against_dark']
                        + df['against_dragon']
                        + df['against_electric']
                        + df['against_fairy']
                        + df['against_fight']
                        + df['against_fire']
                        + df['against_flying']
                        + df['against_ghost']
                        + df['against_grass']
                        + df['against_ground']
                        + df['against_ice']
                        + df['against_normal']
                        + df['against_poison']
                        + df['against_psychic']
                        + df['against_rock']
                        + df['against_steel']
                        + df['against_water']) / 18  
df['bst-weakness-ratio'] = df['bst'] / df['average_weakness']  # ratio of BST:avg weakness - the higher the better
names = df["name"]  # pull out list of all names for creating combinations
combinations = itertools.combinations(names, 6) # create all possible combinations of 6 pokemon teams
top_10_teams = []  # list for storing top 10 teams
for x in combinations:
    ratio = sum(df.loc[df['name'].isin(x)]['bst-weakness-ratio'])  # pull out sum of team's ratio
    if(len(top_10_teams) != 10):
        top_10_teams.append((x, ratio))  # first 10 teams will automatically populate list
    else:
        top_10_teams.append((x, ratio))  # add team to list
        top_10_teams.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)  # sort list by descending ratios
        del top_10_teams[-1]  # drop team with the lowest ratio - only top 10 remain in list
top_10_teams
```

Comment: How long does it take if you restrict to combinations of 2? Or even 1 if possible?

Comment: Well I don't know much about Pokemon but I would first say that there surely is a way to not iterate over all possible combinations of six Pokemon (six fire Pokemon will surely not be in the 10 best teams for instance) so you could first try to think of a way to get a subset of the 3.31e12 combinations that you currently have! Then, I would advise you to subset the possible combinations in smaller groups (in order to not encounter memory errors) and to try to vectorise what you want to do using `NumPy` arrays rather than `pandas` dataframes.

Comment: How is the progress, did you manage to get the perfect team?

Answer (score 1):

In your example every Pokemon has a bst_weakness-ratio and for the calculation of the team value you do not take into account that the members counterbalance each others weaknesses, but simply sum up the ratios of the 6 members? If so, shouldn't the best team be the one with the 6 best individual Pokemon? I don't get why you need the combinations in your case.

Nevertheless I guess you could remove a lot of the Pokemon's from your list before going into the combinatorics.
If you have a boolean array (n_pokemons, n_types) indicating the weaknesses of each Pokemon with True, you could check if there is a Pokemon with the same weaknesses but a better bst value.

```
# Loop over all pokemon and check if there are other pokemon
# ... with the exact same weaknesses but better stats
#                    -name      -weaknesses           -bst
#                    pokemon A  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...], bst=34.85  -> delete A
#                    pokemon B  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...], bst=43.58
# ... with a subset of the weaknesses and better stats
#                    pokemon A  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...], bst=34.85  -> delete A
#                    pokemon B  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...], bst=43.58
```

I wrote a little snippet using numpy. The values for bst and the weaknesses are 
chosen randomly. With my settings

```
n_pokemons = 1000
n_types = 18
n_min_weaknesses = 1  # number of minimal and maximal weaknesses for each Pokemon 
n_max_weaknesses = 4
```

Only about 30-40 pokemons remain in the list. I am not sure how plausible this is for 'real' pokemons but with such a number a combinatorial search is way more feasible.

```
import numpy as np
# Generate pokemons
name_arr = np.array(['pikabra_{}'.format(i) for i in range(n_pokemons)])
# Random stats
bst_arr = np.random.random(n_pokemons) * 100
# Random weaknesses 
weakness_array = np.zeros((n_pokemons, n_types), dtype=bool)  # bool array indicating the weak types of each pokemon
for i in range(n_pokemons):
    rnd_weaknesses = np.random.choice(np.arange(n_types), np.random.randint(n_min_weaknesses, n_max_weaknesses+1))
    weakness_array[i, rnd_weaknesses] = True


# Remove unnecessary pokemons
i = 0
while i < n_pokemons:
    j = i + 1
    while j < n_pokemons:
        del_idx = None

        combined_weaknesses = np.logical_or(weakness_array[i], weakness_array[j])
        if np.all(weakness_array[i] == weakness_array[j]):
            if bst_arr[j] < bst_arr[i]:
                del_idx = i
            else:
                del_idx = j

        elif np.all(combined_weaknesses == weakness_array[i]) and bst_arr[j] < bst_arr[i]:
            del_idx = i

        elif np.all(combined_weaknesses == weakness_array[j]) and bst_arr[i] < bst_arr[j]:
            del_idx = j

        if del_idx is not None:
            name_arr = np.delete(name_arr, del_idx, axis=0)
            bst_arr = np.delete(bst_arr, del_idx, axis=0)
            weakness_array = np.delete(weakness_array, del_idx, axis=0)
            n_pokemons -= 1

            if del_idx == i:
                i -= 1
                break
            else:
                j -= 1

        j += 1
    i += 1


print(n_pokemons)
```